# Delete rows in a table based on portions of a cell, dates, and count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named computers which looks like this:

```
DomainPrefixedComputername | LastStartUpDate
OLDDOMAIN\Computer1        |2012-01-25
OLDDOMAIN\Computer2        |2012-02-20
OLDDOMAIN\Computer3        |2012-03-03
OLDDOMAIN\Computer4        |2012-04-15
OLDDOMAIN\Computer5        |2012-12-18
\Computer1                 |2012-01-27 (computer was inserted when it had no domain affinity)
NEWDOMAIN\Computer1        |2012-02-01
NEWDOMAIN\Computer2        |2012-02-22
NEWDOMAIN\Computer3        |2012-03-23
```

A process either inserts new DomainPrefixedComputers or updates existing ones.  Changing the process or the Database is not possible.

What I’m trying to do is delete Rows containing the computers with the oldest LastStartUpDate if there is a matching computer in the other domain.  Since it is possible that the computer was put back in the old domain, it is not enough just to delete rows prefixed with OLDDOMAIN.  I also do not want to delete rows in favor of non-prefixed computers.

The following statement gets me a list of non-prefixed computers, and how many where found:

```
SELECT 
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(DomainPrefixedComputername, 'NEWDOMAIN\', '')
, 'OLDDOMAIN\', '' )
, '\', '' ) AS TempDomainPrefixedComputername
, Count(DomainPrefixedComputername) AS _count_
FROM Computers
GROUP BY 
Replace(
Replace(
Replace(DomainPrefixedComputername, 'NEWDOMAIN\', '')
, 'OLDDOMAIN\', '' )
, '\', '' )
```

yields:

```
TempDomainPrefixedComputername | _count_
Computer1                      | 3
Computer2                      | 2
Computer3                      | 2
Computer4                      | 1
Computer5                      | 1
```

This is how I would express what I need:

> Delete row with oldest LastStartUpDate  IF another computer exists
>   with the same name AND the other computer’s prefix is either
>   OLDDOMAIN\ OR NEWDOMAIN\ .

My question is:  How can I complete what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (In my example column names are DomainPrefixedComputername > dom, LastStartUpDate > dt) [Here is SQL-Fiddle-Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fea12/20)

```
;with cte as (
  select dom,dt, 
  case when charindex('\',dom,1)=1 then 0 else 1 end hasDom,
  row_number() over (partition by 
                     substring(dom,charindex('\',dom,1)+1,len(dom)) 
                     order by dt desc) rn                   
  from T
)
delete from cte where rn<>1 and hasDom = 1


--Select * results after deleting
|                 DOM |         DT |
------------------------------------
| OLDDOMAIN\Computer4 | 2012-04-15 |
| OLDDOMAIN\Computer5 | 2012-12-18 |
|          \Computer1 | 2012-01-27 |
| NEWDOMAIN\Computer1 | 2012-02-01 |
| NEWDOMAIN\Computer2 | 2012-02-22 |
| NEWDOMAIN\Computer3 | 2012-03-23 |
```

Comment: That answers my question perfectly! Thank you so much!